# Toggling a CSS class too fast to register?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I've got an HTML5 page with an SVG on it that includes

```
    <path id="outlineCO" class="state included" [details omitted]/>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
    .state {
        fill: #ffff66;
        fill-opacity: 0.7;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke-opacity: 1;
    }
    .state.included {
        fill: cyan;
        fill-opacity: 1; 
        transition: fill 2s ease-in;
    }
    .state.included.new {
        fill: magenta;
        transition: none;
    }
```

The gist is that the states on my U.S. map have a default background; states that are "included" have another background; and states that temporarily also given the class name "new" get another background.

Using jQuery, if I execute the following in Chrome's console,

```
$("#outlineCO").toggleClass("new");
```

I see Colorado's background color change from cyan to magenta, as expected. If I execute the same code *again*, I see Colorado transition from magenta back to cyan over a period of 2 seconds.

However, if I execute either

```
$("#outlineCO").toggleClass("new"); $("#outlineCO").toggleClass("new");
```

or

```
$("#outlineCO").toggleClass("new").toggleClass("new");
```

nothing happens. The color remains blue the whole time. It's as though the addition of "new" to the element hasn't *registered* by the time I remove it. Is there a certain amount of time that has to go by before the addition will register, so that the removal will have the desired effect of switching the state instantly to magenta and then slowly back to cyan?

Comment: The browser has to be given a chance to redraw.  It is not given such a chance for every alteration of the dom.  Which, a question I have is why are you trying to add and remove a class that quickly?  Are you trying to make something blink or flash or what?

Comment: Instead of adding and removing a class to perform this logic, create a class that is associated with a transition with steps.  The steps would instantly change it to magenta, and then gradually change it back.  https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: It's an interactive map that shows the status of several states in a selected year. When a year is selected, states that were already "included" in earlier years are displayed in cyan, while states first included in that year start off magenta and then transition to cyan. (This is the way an existing Flash version of this works. We're rebuilding it in HTML5.)

Suppose 2015 is selected, and Colorado was first "included" in 2009. So it will appear cyan. Now, if the user selects 2009, Colorado needs to go directly to magenta, and then transition back to cyan. That's the effect I'm going for.

Comment: Yeah i'd look at doing that with the css animations, not with javascript

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire to stick to jQuery, you could use the `toggleClass` method from the jQuery UI library (See **[docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)**), which also accepts a duration parameter (ms).

See the snippet below (Duration is set to 1000 ms):

```js
$('#square').toggleClass('new', 1000).toggleClass('new', 1000);
```

```css
#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#square.new {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="square"></div>
```